# How to resolve this recursive dependency?

Tags: php

I've come across a weird issue.

In the class Node I need some of the functionality of Chapter so I've included the Chapter.php file inside Node.php as below:

**Node.php file:**

```
require_once('Model.php');
require_once('Chapter.php');
class Node extends Model {
...
}
```

**Chapter.php file:**

```
require_once('Node.php');
class Chapter extends Node {
...
}
```

**Error:**

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Node' not found in Chapter.php
```

How come it doesn't find the Node class? What are some ways around this?

Comment: most likely its some include path issue.. can u confirm the class files are in the same level.

Comment: Yes the files are in the same level. I'm 100% certain.

Comment: You have design problems, try to re-write the classes. Try to [decouple](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=php+decoupling+classes&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=php+decoupl&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3j69i64.5648j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) your dependencies.

Comment: Remove the includes from included classes.  Include each file as needed (once) or use an [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: In addition:

- Since PHP 5.3 you can use [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)
 - Otherwise you can use the [spl_autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what your code is doing:

1. [Node.php line 1] Load (no more than once) Model.php - so it does that
2. [Node.php line 2] Load (no more than once) Chapter.php - so it does that
3. [Chapter.php line 1] Load (no more than once) Node.php - we've already started doing that, so since it's `require_once`, there's no need to do that again
4. [Chapter.php line 2] Create a class Chapter extending Node - since we haven't yet gotten to line 3 of Node.php, there's no class `Node` that we know about

The best solution is to move whatever functionality you need in Node from Chapter somewhere else, possibly into Node. Classes should not depend on the functionality of their children.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using an [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

For instance, put this somewhere in the beginning of your application

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Then when you

```
new Chapter();
```

PHP will automatically include `chapter.php` if the class isn't already loaded.  When trying to load `chapter.php` it will realize it needs a class called `Node` and will include `node.php` if that class isn't already loaded, etc.